# PHP Range Function

Tags: php

I need some help w/ range function:

Code: `range(1,4)`

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

---

How can I get an output like:

```
Array
(
    [01] => 01
    [02] => 02
    [03] => 03
    [04] => 04
)
```

Comment: Integers have no leading zeros. You should add zeros only when presenting.

Comment: For values, i understand but what difference does it make in keys?

Comment: In using to complete a FORM SELECT of DAYS (1-31), and as MySQL store data as 2000-01-01 I can only compare if its 01 instead 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the values, you *could* use a string instead. There is [an example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php#109642) using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to help you, and also with [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to pad zeros:

```
<?php
$a = array_map(function($n) { return sprintf('%02d', $n); }, range(1, 4));
print_r($a);
?>
```

In older PHP versions you may need this:

```
<?php
function f($n) { return sprintf('%02d', $n); }
$a = array_map(f, range(1, 4));
print_r($a);
?>
```

Output:
Array

```
(
    [0] => 01
    [1] => 02
    [2] => 03
    [3] => 04
)
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/Ovx1VQDM

But Array keys are intended for use in your code only, even though you could use strings as keys, it would be better to stay with integers.

Comment: I want an output like: array { [01]=>01, [02]=>02... }

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array()
foreach (range(1, 4) as $value) {
  $array[str_pad($value, 1, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT)] = str_pad($value, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```